# Abort on the MAC system when the "run" command is run in GDB

Tags: macos, gdb

My system is Mac OS X El Capitan
I use "brew install gdb" is version 8.1
Abort when the "run" command is run in gdb. The following figure： 
[image]

Comment: However, the normal output "hello world" when I use lldb is debugged

Comment: Be aware that gdb is not the right way to debug programs in MacOS, standard is llvm+lldb. Making gdb running on mac is too hard to worth the effort, switch to lldb.

Comment: Thank you. I've given up gdb and turned to lldb.